# How does bringing all the features in same range as target variable impact performance?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, categorical-data, dimensionality-reduction, feature-engineering

Suppose I have the following dataset. (The data is completely random)

```
Colour  Size       Shape        Pre booking number  Price
White   24         Square          600              1400
Blue    35         Circle          435              1854
Black   16         Square          873              1272
White   43         Triangle        221              1777
White   20         Oval            532              1434
Black   35         Triangle        221              ????
```

I have to predict the price for a certain combination of [Colour,Size,Shape,Pre Booking Number]

Consider the following approach for feature engineering
I take Colour v/s Price. I groupby Colour to find out mean price for each group(colour), and simply replace the Colour variable by their respective mean. I do this for every categorical variable. For non-categorical variable, I leave them as they are.

```
Colour  Size        Shape   Pre booking number      Price
1536    1400        1336        600                 1400
1854    1854        1854        435                 1854
1272    1272        1336        873                 1272
1536    1777        1777        221                 1777
1536    1434        1434        532                 1434
1272    1854        1777.       221                 ????
```

And now I feed this data to any ML regression model.

My questions are:

1. How good/bad is this approach? What happens internally?
2. In general, how effective is it to bring all the variables in strong correlation with target variable, perhaps on same scale?
3. On the top of this, if I merge two or more categorical columns just by adding/multiplying to reduce dimensions, how will it impact prediction?

Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly don't you use the features as they are (at least in a first step)? It seems unclear what you try to achieve by your approach.

Comment: He's trying to reduce the dimensionality of his data.

Comment: @MarijnvanVliet He still has the same amount of dimensions in his example after feature engineering. And again: Why is this necessary if he has only 4 features and the dependent variables?

Comment: @petezurich: This was a sample case with 4 features for the sake of understanding and discussion. The features I am trying to deal with are categorial, so encoding them is one way but that creates (total categories - 1) features in replacement for that one feature. So I was just looking for another approach.

Comment: @petezurich :  Also, if able to convert the categorical features efficiently at a understandable numerical scale, I might be able to combine the features which will be helpful if I have say 80-90 categorical variables to process.

Answer (score 4):

1. As far as I know, one hot encoding to nominal features like color and shape performs better. Putting integer values like you have done adds an additional value to blue over white which doesn't make sense. You are already assuming a high correlation between color and price which may or may not be wrong. I would run a Sequential Backward Selection to check the actual importance of the features.If color and price are highly correlated your approach might be correct and you should now scale the features.
2. It is highly effective to bring features to same scale as it helps to  give a justified importance to each feature. If a feature is in the order of thousands and is left unscaled the weights might give undue importance to that feature. It is obvious that features that have a high correlation with target variable should be included in training.
3. Merging two categorical columns which are not correlated will hamper your results. On the other hand if they are highly correlated then you could merge them.
   I am however unsure if you should even take the pain of dimensionality reduction for this dataset where there are not many feature columns present.
   Nevertheless here's a thread if you would like to know how to combine two features which are weakly correlated to each other but highly correlated to target variable:
   https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/110984

Here's another good article on data filtering: 
https://towardsdatascience.com/data-correlation-can-make-or-break-your-machine-learning-project-82ee11039cc9

Finally, commenting on a certain approach might not be accurate. You always need to see how much correlated they are and try out different approaches and models. Check if your data has linear or non-linear correlation and choose your model accordingly. Doing complex modifications on a relatively simple data and using unnecessarily complex models may not always be a good approach.

Comment: Hi Rik. Thanks for those insights. 
1. This was a sample case with 4 variable. I was using this approach where I had some 80-90 categorical variables (before trying one hot encoding hence). Though not very thoroughly, but I tried to induce some correlation between color and price by replacing colors with mean price of respective categories. In that sense, with pretty large data set, do you think its fairly wise to consider blue better(costlier) than white?
Thanks for your insight on the approach.